# I am trying to scrape a website using beautifulsoup4 and requests library

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the movie name, year and length of the movie from this website

Below is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www4.f2movies.to'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Trending Movies
Movies = []
Year = []
Length = []

for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True, attrs={'class':"film-detail film-detail-fix"}):
    name=data.find('div', href=True, attrs={'class':'film-name'})
    year=data.find('span', href=True, attrs={'class':'fdi-item'})
    length=data.find('span', href=True, attrs={'class':'fdi-item fdi-duration'})
    Movies.append(name.text)
    Year.append(year.text)
    Length.append(length.text)

print(Movies)
print(Year)
print(Length)
```

The result that I am getting is like something below:

```
(Projects) anildhage@xxx-MacBook-Air WebScrape % python scrape.py
[]
[]
[]
(Projects) anildhage@xxx-MacBook-Air WebScrape %
```

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? TIA

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your selectors when using `find()` we're incorrect. To get all data use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www4.f2movies.to"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# Trending Movies
Movies = []
Year = []
Length = []

for data in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "film-detail film-detail-fix"}):
    name = data.find("h3", attrs={"class": "film-name"})
    year = data.find("span", attrs={"class": "fdi-item"})
    length = data.find("span", attrs={"class": "fdi-item fdi-duration"})
    if not length:
        continue

    Movies.append(name.text.strip())
    Year.append(year.text)
    Length.append(length.text)


print(Movies)
print(Year)
print(Length)
```

Output:

```
["Tom Clancy's Without Remorse", 'The Mitchells vs. The Machines', 'Mortal Kombat', 'Things Heard & Seen', 'Demon Slayer the Movie: Mugen Train', 'Voyagers', 'Tom & Jerry', 'Godzilla vs. Kong', 'Justice Society: World War II', 'Nomadland', 'The Virtuoso', 'Shadow in the Cloud', 'Nobody', 'Skylines', "Zack Snyder's Justice League", 'Stowaway', '22 vs. Earth', 'The Marksman', 'The Little Things', 'Wonder Woman 1984', 'Raya and the Last Dragon', 'The Father', 'SAS: Red Notice', 'Come True', 'The Lockdown Hauntings', 'The Bike Thief', 'Generation Por Que', 'Adolescents of Chymera', 'The Darkness', 'The Rise of Sir Longbottom', 'Mexican Moon', "She was the Deputy's Wife", '100m Criminal Conviction', 'Percy', 'The Mitchells vs. The Machines', 'Zombie with a Shotgun', 'Things Heard & Seen', 'Golden Arm', 'Bang! Bang!', 'Colors of Love', 'Three Pints and a Rabbi', 'Eat Wheaties!', "Before I'm Dead", '22 vs. Earth', 'The Outside Story', 'Voyagers', 'Ape vs. Monster', 'Pipeline']
['2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2019', '2021', '2021', '2020', '2021', '2021', '2020', '0000', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021', '2021']
['109m', '113m', '110m', '121m', '117m', '108m', '90m', '113m', 'N/A', '108m', '105m', '83m', '92m', '110m', '242m', '116m', '5m', '108m', '127m', '151m', '112m', '97m', '120m', '105m', '101m', '79m', 'N/A', '81m', 'N/A', '73m', '84m', '95m', '92m', '109m', '113m', '79m', '121m', '90m', '71m', '110m', '85m', 'N/A', '83m', '5m', '85m', '108m', '90m', '85m']
```

Comment: Great thank you ... although could you mention why it was necessary to use - If statement and the .strip() attribute ?

Comment: @AnilDhage 1. sometimes `length` is `None`, so we need to check that the value is not empty. 2. using `.strip()` would remove extra whitespace (see what happens when you remove it).